# "Access denied for user, using password: yes" Laravel 8 Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku

Here is the `config/database.php` file that I modified using this [tutorial](https://dev.to/jsafe00/deploy-laravel-application-with-database-to-heroku-l50). It says that I need to attach the `$DATABASE_URL=parse_url("mysql://####");` code block above the said php page. (the tutorial is using postgreSQL, while my system needs to use MySQL).

```
// attached $DATABASE_URL=parse_url("mysql://####") on the topmost part of the page


'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => $DATABASE_URL['host'], // edited this line
            'port' => $DATABASE_URL['port'], // edited this line
            'database' => ltrim($DATABASE_URL['path'], '/'), // edited this line
            'username' => $DATABASE_URL['user'], // edited this line
            'password' => $DATABASE_URL['pass'], // edited this line
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

below is the original mysql code

```
        // 'mysql' => [
        //     'driver' => 'mysql',
        //     'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        //     'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        //     'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        //     'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        //     'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        //     'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        //     'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        //     'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        //     'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        //     'prefix' => '',
        //     'prefix_indexes' => true,
        //     'strict' => true,
        //     'engine' => null,
        //     'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        //         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        //     ]) : [],
        // ],
```

error ouput when running the system with the said problem

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user '{{redacted username}}'@'{{redacted ip address}}' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `video_links` where `home_video` = true and `video_links`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

Another problem I encounter while running the migration command in the Heroku CLI is this:

```
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "port" in /app/config/database.php on line 51
```

It seems like the `$DATABASE_URL=parse_url("mysql://####")` is not fetching the port value in its array.

How should I approach this?

Comment: did you add 
:3306 to the end of your host 
example: mysql://user:pass@example.com:3306/dbname

Comment: yes, it is included in the link as `:3306`

Comment: please print out $DATABASE_URL and check it structure if the link is correct then it should have structure like this
Array
(
    [scheme] => mysql
    [host] => example.com
    [port] => 3306
    [user] => user
    [pass] => pass
    [path] => /dbname
)

Comment: is it possible to print this out? if so, can I do it on the `database.php`?

Comment: You attach it on top of the file right, just print it there and add exit() to make program stop for you can see

Answer (score 1):

You can leave `config/database.php` unchanged.

And add an ENV var `DATABASE_URL`:

In the settings or via CLI:

`heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=YOUR_URL`